# How to count distinct values in a sequence of four numbers from 0 to 10?

Tags: java, numbers, comparison

Given a sequence of four numbers in a scale of 0 to 10, how can I extract how many of the numbers are unique?

For example:

- 10, 10, 10, 10 = 1 number
- 10,10,9,10 = 2 different numbers
- 10,8,7,9 = 4 different numbers
- 10, 9, 10, 8 = 3 different numbers

Comment: Class: perhaps no. Code: yes, its in your mind, you just have to unleash it.

Answer (score 1):

A `Set<Integer>` such as a `HashSet<Integer>` could simplify things since it would not allow duplicates. It will allow you to call the add method on duplicates to the Set, but if the Set already contains the item, the add method will do nothing other than return `false`. Getting the `size()` of the set after adding all items, will tell you how many non-duplicate items exist.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to notice here is that the exercise is not really about the numbers [0,10]. It really is about having four distinct elements, which can either be the same or not the same. (They could be numbers, letters of the Latin alphabet, apples, bananas, oranges etc.)

We are looking for a function (x1,x2,x3,x4) -> n where, in this specific case, every x is an integer [0,10] and n is always the number of distinct elements in the tuple, rangig from 1 to the length of the tuple, in this case 4. (To have exactly 4 numbers is also quite arbitrary.)

To expand on Hovercraft's answer, the `Set` interface and its implementation, e.g. `HashSet`, provide a cheap, pratical solution here:

```
public int getDistinctCount(int x1, int x2, int x3, int x4) {
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    set.add(x1);
    set.add(x2);
    set.add(x3);
    set.add(x4);
    int count = set.size();
    return count;
}
```

This works, because in essence, the exercise asks us to map tuple (or multiset) characteristics to set characteristics. Given a tuple t, what would be its cardinality if it was a set?

To understand what's going on (in case that's not absolutely clear to you) it is worthwhile to read the source code of `HashSet` (and `AbstractSet` from there...) and think about how we would implement this if both classes didn't exist.

Basically, we need to iterate over the list of four (or how many there are) numbers and keep track of the elements we've already seen. For every element, we need to iterate over the elements we've already seen to find out if it's new to us. If yes, we increment a "distinct elements" counter. Alternatively, we can count the distinct elements in the end, as in the solution above.